# Switch Owning Side of OneToOne Relationship on Production System

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm refactoring our entity setup for performance reasons. Specifically, I want to **switch the owning side of a OneToOne relationship**. (Mainly cause I had set it wrong in the first place...).

Problem: I want to do this on a live system

Question: What is the best way to this:

- Not losing data
- Using Doctrine Migrations

---

Essentially I want to move the `reference_id` field with all its data and move it to the other side of the relationship.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

---

Here is one example for two related Entities

```
<?php

class Auction 
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="AuctionParameter", mappedBy="auction", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    protected $auction_parameter;
}

class AuctionParameter
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Auction", inversedBy="auction_parameter")
     */
    protected $auction;
}
```

Auction should hold the reference Id instead of Parameters

Comment: Can you give us the two table names plz?! I will write out a PHP script example to solve your problem when I get a few mins.

Comment: @Preciel updated.

Comment: So, as I understand, Auction should become the owning side right?! Where does `reference_id` come from? If Doctrine generated the database, then `reference_id` should be called `auction_id` in the `auction_parameter` table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your edit, I will assume that `reference_id` is actually `auction_id` owned by the table `auction_parameter`

First thing first, you should make a copy of your database (just the two tables should be enough) to test out my script. I'm not perfect (far from it), I might have made a mistake.

Before executing the script, you have to add a new column in your `auction` table.
I would suggest to do it outside of the php script down there (so via PphMyAdmin for example)

```
ALTER TABLE `auction` ADD `auction_parameter_id` INT(11) NULL;
ALTER TABLE `auction_parameter` MODIFY `auction_id` INT(11) NULL;
```

Then switch the owning side in your two entities.

<kbd>**AuctionEntity**</kbd>

```
class Auction 
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="AuctionParameter", inversedBy="auction", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    protected $auction_parameter;
}
```

<kbd>**AuctionParameterEntity**</kbd>

```
class AuctionParameter
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Auction", mappedBy="auction_parameter")
     */
    protected $auction;
}
```

Save it, but don't update SQL schema yet, else you will loose everything.
Doing this for now will assure that new entries are already on the right owning side.

Just in case, you should dump the schema changes to make sure that the new column in the `Auction` table will be called `auction_parameter_id`
If not, adjust the first SQL query above.

```
php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql
```

Now that the `auction` table is ready to welcome the owned key, running this script should do the trick:

```
$pdoLink=null;
$PARAM_HOST='localhost';
$PARAM_USER='db_user';
$PARAM_PASSWD='db_passwd';
$PARAM_DB='db_name';
$PARAM_CHARSET='utf8';
try {
    $pdoLink=new PDO("mysql:host=$PARAM_HOST;dbname=$PARAM_DB;charset=$PARAM_CHARSET", $PARAM_USER, $PARAM_PASSWD);
    $pdoLink->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(Exception $e) {
    echo 'Erreur : '.$e->getMessage().'<br />NР: '.$e->getCode();
    exit();
}
$data=array();
$sth=$pdoLink->prepare(/** @lang MySQL */
    "SELECT `auction_parameter`.`id` AS `owned`, `auction_parameter`.`auction_id` AS `owner`
    FROM `auction_parameter`
    WHERE `auction_parameter`.`auction_id` IS NOT NULL");
if($sth !== false && $sth->execute()) {
    while($row=$sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        array_push($data, $row);
    }
    foreach($data as $datum) {
        $sth=$pdoLink->prepare(/** @lang MySQL */
            "UPDATE `auction`
            SET `auction`.`auction_parameter_id`=:owned_side
            WHERE `auction`.`id`=:owner_side");
        $sth->bindParam(':owned_side', $datum['owned'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $sth->bindParam(':owner_side', $datum['owner'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        if($sth !== false) {
            $sth->execute();
        }
    }
}
$sth->closeCursor();
$pdoLink=null;
```

This should do what you need. Now all you have to do is to update SQL schema with doctrine. (You might have to drop the `foreign_key` and the `aucion_id` column manually as there is data in it)

```
php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

Comment: hey man, thanks for the script! I was just wondering if there is a "doctrine way" to do this. But I guess your answer ist correct. I'll just have to migrate the reference ids by hand.

Comment: I don't think there is a "doctrine way"... At least I do not know one